# What is IBM PowerLinux?

Tags: linux

I've just heard about something called IBM PowerLinux, but i don't find a clear definition of what it is. Can someone please explain this in few words ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it from [IBM's web site](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/linux/about/index.html), it's just a buzzword for Linux running on servers that use the [IBM POWER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_POWER) architecture.

> PowerLinux servers, software and solutions are built on our Power Systems platform and associated services, and should be the open standard platform of choice for deploying new Linux technology–based applications, offering superior capabilities for big data analytics, industry application solutions, open source infrastructure services, and other emerging workloads.

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean. Thank you for your answer !